# Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS: No language bar available

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, mate

For a while now, I have been struggling and googling as to a simple problem. I need to use three layouts on this computer (nothing special, just a box I built using an old Intel board and a Pentium Dual-Core CPU), and while I can add them easily, no matter what, the language bar (normally located in the top right corner, with the sound and wifi controls, etc.) doesn't appear - and if I want to switch, I can only do it from Control Panel->Keyboard.

Other computers with the same exact distro have the language bar just fine. Is it a problem anyone here knows how to solve, or can I simply download an alternative method?

Thanks!

Comment: have you set a keyboard shortcut to switch? I use MATE and I had some trouble with the panel indicator for a while, but now it is behaving, and all I know is that I added the layout I wanted, the panel icon appeared, then I set a keyboard shortcut, the panel icon disappeared, I removed and added the layout again, and it came back, but disappeared on reboot a few times before settling down!

Comment: Hi there. No. I have not set keyboard shortcuts, but lest a solution will be found here, I suppose I will have to :)

Comment: If you press keyboard layout switching shortcut does it change layout?  Have you set layouts and shortcut in `mate-keyboard-properties`? With at least two layouts it should have keyboard layout indicator in mate-panel.

Comment: A keyboard shortcut does change layout, yes! Still no indicator though - perhaps my case is such as with Zanna, and it will first act... arbitrarily. I'll report back tomorrow.

Comment: Still no indicator, I'm afraid.